# QComboBox relation between editTextChanged and currentIndexChanged

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

Usage of the signal `currentIndexChanged` is clear, it's triggered when a different item from combobox is selected. But I'm facing a problem with the other signal. `editTextChanged` is triggered when the `editText` of combobox is changed manually by the user overwriting it, but also when another item from combobox is selected, so both `editTextChanged` and `currentIndexChanged` are triggered.

My problem is that I need to know which one of these two possibilities is happening in my slot `on_comboBox_editTextChanged()`, whether the text was overwritten or a different item was selected. From what I saw, the slot `on_comboBox_editTextChanged()` is called the first, so I don't know how to achieve this information in the slot.

I haven't found anything in the `QComboBox` class which could solve it. So the question is how to differentiate whether editTextChanged was triggered because of index was changed or user overwritten the editText?

Answer (score 3):

Editable `QComboBox` will have an ***associated*** default `linedit` set object, which also can be interfaced directly for signals, like: `textEdited` , so you may opt to use an alternative to the `&QComboBox::editTextChanged` signal, with `textEdited` Signal of the `linedit` object, for instance:

```
connect(ui->comboBox->lineEdit(), &QLineEdit::textEdited, this, &MainWindow::textEdited);
```

So, in this case, when you select an item in the combobox, you will only get the QComboBox signal `currentTextChanged`, but not the `textEdited` which is a distinguish for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the index of the selected item in the `editTextChanged` handler. If -1 is returned, then the text was edited, else the item was selected from the drop down list. If the text was typed in the text box but it exists in the drop down list, it is the same case as user selected the item from the drop down list.

> `currentIndex : int`
>
> This property holds the index of the current item in the combobox.
>
> The current index can change when inserting or removing items.
>
> By default, for an empty combo box or a combo box in which no current item is set, this property has a value of -1.

Comment: This worked for me on NodeJS implementation of Qt (nodegui). Thank you!